# Reduce expressions into (simplified) matrix and vector forms

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, vector

I have some computation that results in a rather complicated looking expression that could be much simplified by converting it into matrix or vector expressions. For example, instead of `x0 y0 + x1 y1 + x2 y2` appearing, it would be simpler to have $x^T y$.

A simple example, after declaring `xi={xi0,xi1,xi2}`, etc:

```
In[43]:= Dot[xi, xj]

Out[43]= xi0 xj0 + xi1 xj1 + xi2 xj2
```

How do I reduce that Out[43] back into a matrix expression? i.e. `In[43]` itself is actually simpler than `Out[43]`. The final expressions I'm working with are generated by taking derivatives of matrix/vector expressions and are multiple lines long and involve both matrix and vector operations.

This is more about computational considerations than pure simplicity, I'm OK with ugly auto-generated code; I want to convert these Mathematica results into C++ code, and the vector expressions can result in a lot more efficient code through SSE instructions, more efficient matrix multiplications, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With

`xi={xi0,xi1,xi2}`

we do

`xj = Last@Normal@CoefficientArrays[xi0 xj0 + xi1 xj1 + xi2 xj2, xi]`

such that

```
Dot @@ {xi, xj}
```

yields

> `xi0 xj0 + xi1 xj1 + xi2 xj2`

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question?

Comment: @Sean We have an equation; the one from the OP. Given a vector `xi` -which is defined from your post- I am obtaining another vector `xj` such that the `Dot` product yields the original algebraic equation. You explicitly mentioned that you wanted the `Dot` product to give you back the equation. From the way the post is written this is what I understood you wanted. It is possible I misunderstood what you wanted to do and/or you mis-wrote what you wanted.  Perhaps you could offer some clarifications.

Comment: `Dot @@ {xi, xj}` == `Dot[xi, xj]` == `xi.xj`

Comment: if you had an issue with the syntax, please have a look at the comment that @AsukaMinato left